# How can I split a string and sum all numbers from that string?

Tags: google-sheets, split

I'm making a list for buying groceries in Google Sheets and have the following value in cell B4.

```
0.95 - Lemon Juice 
2.49 - Pringle Chips
1.29 - Baby Carrots
9.50 - Chicken Kebab
```

What I'm trying to do is split using the dash character and combine the costs (0.95+2.49+1.29+9.50).

I've tried to use `Index(SPLIT(B22,"-"), 7)` and `SPLIT(B22,"-")` but I don't know how to use only numbers from the split string.

Does someone know how to do this? Here's a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/192qCvSTEi89v8guJo3hss2O_KXF-pe0JxRg--r_Z7-o/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

The following formula should produce the result you desire:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(B4,CHAR(10)),"(.*)-"))))
```

### Explanation

The first thing to do is to split the entry in B4 into its component parts. This is done by using the `=SPLIT` function, which takes the text in B4 and returns a separate result every time it encounters a specific delimiter. In this case, that is `=CHAR(10)`, the newline character.

Next, all non-number information needs to be removed. This is relatively easy in your sample data because the numbers always appear to the left of a dash. `=REGEXEXTRACT` uses a regular expression to only return the text to the left of the dash.

Before the numbers can be added together, however, they must be converted to be in a number format. The `=VALUE` function is used to convert each result from a text string containing a number to an *actual* number.

All of this is wrapped in an `=ARRAYFORMULA` so that `=VALUE` and `=REGEXEXTRACT` parse each returned value from `=SPLIT`, rather than just the first.

Finally, all results are added together using `=SUM`.

Functions used:

- [=CHAR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094120?hl=en)
- [=SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en)
- [=REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en)
- [=VALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094220?hl=en)
- [=ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)
- [=SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can add `,` symbols start and ends of numbers with below code:

```
REGEXREPLACE(B4,"([0-9\.]+)",",$1,")
```

Then split it based of `,` sign.

```
SPLIT(A8, ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula (see your sheet)-

```
=SUM(ArrayFormula(--REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(B4,CHAR(10)),"-*\d*\.?\d+")))
```

[image]